# Invalid block tag on line 10: 'static'/css/all.css''. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

am getting Invalid block tag on line 10: 'static'/css/all.css''. Did you forget to register or load this tag? when i run my django app.
here is my code:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static'/css/all.css'%}">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static'/css/bootstrap.css'%}">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static'/css/style.css'%}">

    <title>BT Real Estate</title>
</head>
```

here is my static settings

```
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [`enter code here`
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'btre/static')
]
```

Comment: add spaces! change `{% static'/css/all.css'%}` to `{% static '/css/all.css' %}` and similarly other lines.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat use comments to ask clarification or suggest improvements. Please avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to spacing in `{% static'/css/all.css'%}` the above comment by @ Abdul Aziz Barkat is correct.

Try this:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

    <title>BT Real Estate</title>
</head>
```